# PhantomJs strips all the XML tags from RSS feed

Tags: javascript, xml, rss, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to parse information out of an RSS feed for testing. I am using CasperJS for tests and PhantomJS for capturing screenshots. When I navigate to the RSS feed, I took a screenshot and saw that all the XML tags are stripped and its just text. I need the tags as I need the pubDate tag value from the feed for my tests. 
Can I in anyway get the feed in the original form ?

```
checkRSSFeed = function() {
    //first I navigate to a certain page in my website
    var href = '';

    casper.then(function() {
        this.test.assertExists(x('//a[contains(@href, "SUBSTRING OF URL")]'), 'the element exists');
        href = casper.getElementAttribute(x('//a[contains(@href, "SUBSTRING OF URL")]'), 'href');
     }).then(function() {
        this.open(href);
     }).then(function() {
        this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
        casper.capture(PATH_TO_SCREENSHOT);
     });
};
```

Below is a screenshot of the version of RSS seen by PhantomJS

[image]

Comment: So the `href` variable contains the rss feed url? The `capture` should be done inside of a step. You're not getting the correct screenshot. What does `casper.getPageContent()` return?

Comment: My apologies for the incorrect code, capturing is actually inside the 'then' function. This error creeped in as I actually typed this code here. I have fixed that. But yes, href contains rss feed url (sorry for the bad variable name) And the capture inside 'then' function gives a screenshot of RSS feed with no xml tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhantomJS is a browser which interprets arbitrary markup as HTML. So even when you specifically open the RSS feed as a page it will try to render the HTML. But since RSS elements (tags) don't have a meaning as HTML they are rendered as a generic block element.

Some browsers in fact show RSS feeds in a specific way when they encounter them, but not so PhantomJS. All it means is that `casper.capture` is the wrong tool for the job. You need [`casper.getPageContent`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getpagecontent) to return the complete page content (which is the RSS feed source).

You can still do things on the RSS feed elements ([`casper.getElementAttribute`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementattribute) and others still work), but be aware that when you specifically have to select elements based on namespaces, then a [slight workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931073/how-to-select-tags-with-namespaces-in-casperjs) has to be done. If you don't want to use namespace specific selectors, either use CSS selectors or XPath expressions with `local-name()` such as `//*[local-name()='link']`.

Comment: So apparently, my code fix is not working. Please look at the edit in my code. pubDate is not being updated; I verified my XPATH and it is correct. I tried to assert if pubDate exists and it fails there. Any thoughts ?

Comment: You edited your question into another. My answer wouldn't make sense anymore for a future reader. Your original problem is solved. Please ask a new question if you have a further problem. When you do, don't forget to include a sample XML and what XPath expression you tried.

Comment: Well, how can I verify if getPageContent() is actually getting the page in its original format ? I know what getPageContent does but is there any way I could verify it ? Without that, the original question itself is not verified, right ?

Comment: Well, it does work. You're probably doing something wrong. Perhaps you're trying to select some element from the feed content which is xml escaped. [Proof of concept](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/20e0f685f2d7723b1e8f)

Comment: I just realized I might have made a very silly mistake. I am looking for pubDate element in the RSS feed and it does not have any attribute. It just has a date in it and that is what I need. I think getElementAttribute() won't work. I might have to use the client utils module and then use getElementByXPath(). Do you think this is what I should be doing ?

Comment: Excuse my silliness; still pretty new to front end stuff.

Comment: Again, I can't help if I don't know how your XML/feed looks.

Comment: Ok. Shall I post the xml in a new question ?

Comment: Yes, that will be probably better. If you tag it with [casperjs] I will see it. Don't need to notify specifically.